# Atribuir valor no input

Tags: php, script

Tenho este código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(function() {
  $('#Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
})
</script>

$tabela1 .= '<td style="font-size: 12px"> <input type="text" name= "Preco['.$rows_cursos['IdRequisicao'].']" id= "Preco" value="0.00"></td>';
```

Quando o utilizador utiliza a coluna preço para inserir o valor, só a primeira linha da tabela funciona corretamente, como mostro na imagem:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Atributo `id` do HTML **deve ser único** na página. Ele é o identificador do elemento - assim como seu CPF. Mude sua lógica para algo que não seja o `id` que talvez funcione.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema ocorre porque o `id` é um atributo **único** podendo haver apenas **1**, se substituir pelo atributo `class`, funciona perfeitamente

```
<input type="text" name="" class="Preco">
<input type="text" name="" class="Preco">
<input type="text" name="" class="Preco">

<script>
    $(function() {
      $('.Preco').maskMoney({ decimal: '.', thousands: ' ', precision: 2 });
    })
</script>
```